# Do I need to run both nginx and jetty on the server machine?

Tags: nginx, clojure, jetty

I've set up nginx in a laptop running ubuntu and I will be using this machine as the server.

But I am programming with Clojure on an OS X laptop and I installed Jetty on OS X. I compiled the .war file on the OS X and run Jetty server on the OS X.

Now I realize that this is probably wrong. Should Jetty be also running on the ubuntu server? Can you explain the correct way to work with this set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to have both servers on one machine. Nginx can forward requests to other server by ip

```
upstream jetty {
  server 192.168.1.33:3000;
}
```

You need to be sure port is opened and accessible (not firewalled) from nginx machine.

```
> telnet 192.168.1.33 3000
```

Both nginx and jetty should run on server, on dev running just jetty is fine unless you test "like-production" environment (for example nginx websockets support).

Comment: Thanks. But does this mean that my OS X laptop where I have Jetty needs to be running all the time so that Jetty server can run?

Comment: Yes, that's why it's better to setup production server. Dev machine doesn't need to be running all the time.

Comment: Ok, so, you are saying that I should install Jetty on the ubuntu server and run it there. Does this mean that I need to create my clojure project on the server machine and do all the programming there? In other words, core.clj needs to be on the server?

Comment: You don't need to copy source to production server. uberjar/war already contains your sources compiled.